# Изменённое свойства в сущности отображается не сразу

Tags: php, symfony

Использую Symfony 6.3.0
На сайте есть тёмная тема и светлая тема.
Соответственно сущность User имеет свойство darkTheme = true || false
В профиле юзера есть настройки, в которых он может изменить тему на светлую или тёмную, кликнув на radio.
Написал для реализации контроллер

```
/**
 * @Route(path="/settings", name=".settings")
 */
public function settings(Request $request, Handler $handler): Response
{
    $command = new Command($this->getUser()->getId(), $this->getUser()->getdark_theme());
    
    $form = $this->createForm(Form::class, $command);
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    
    if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()){
        try {
            $handler->handle($command);
            $this->addFlash("success", "Settings was successfully updated.");
        } catch (\DomainException $e) {
            $this->logger->warning($e->getMessage(), ['exception' => $e]);
            $this->addFlash("error", $e->getMessage());
        }
    }

    return $this->render("app/dashboard/user/settings.html.twig", [
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ]);
}
```

Form:

```
class Form extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder
            ->add("dark_mode", ChoiceType::class, [
                'choices' => [
                    'Dark Mode' => 1,
                    'Light Mode' => 0,
                ],
                'multiple' => false,
                'expanded' => true,
            ]);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Command::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Handler, который сохраняет изменённую сущность в БД:

```
class Handler
{
    private UserRepository $users;
    private Flusher $flusher;

    public function __construct(UserRepository $users, Flusher $flusher)
    {
        $this->users = $users;
        $this->flusher = $flusher;
    }

    public function handle(Command $command): void
    {
        $user = $this->users->get($command->id);

        $user->setDarkTheme(
            (bool)$command->dark_mode
        );

        $this->flusher->flush();
    }
}
```

И всё работает корректно - настройка меняется. Но проблема визуально состоит в том, что:
Например, у юзера установлена светлая тема и он желает изменить её на тёмную.
Он идёт в настройки, кликает на radio Dark Mode и кликает кнопку Submit. Происходит отправка формы, юзера редиректит на эту же страницу, показывается флеш-сообщение "Settings was successfully updated.". Но тема так и остаётся старой - светлой. А уж если затем перейти на любую другую страницу сайта - появляется уже тёмная тема.
Вопрос: почему так происходит? И как исправить это? (Что бы после сабмита формы сразу появлялась выбранная тема).

Comment: В контроллере `public function settings` юзера __никуда не редиректит__. Поэтому страничка загружается с необновленным значением темы, тут же тема обновляется, но страничка рендерится с предыдущим значением темы.

Comment: Благодарю! В этом и была проблема.